# DateFormatter not outputting wrong date

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsdateformatter

I am trying to do a date from string however it always makes the date in the month of January... Why?

Code:

```
NSMutableArray *dateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMDD"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

for (id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo in [fetchedResultsController sections]) {
    NSLog(@"Adding date: %@", [sectionInfo name]);
    NSDate *newDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[sectionInfo name]];
    NSLog(@"Adding date 2: %@", newDate);
    [dateArray addObject:newDate];
}
```

LOGS:

```
2012-03-01 15:14:48.124 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date: 20120827
2012-03-01 15:14:48.124 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date 2: 2012-01-27 00:00:00 +0000
2012-03-01 15:14:48.125 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date: 20120830
2012-03-01 15:14:48.125 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date 2: 2012-01-30 00:00:00 +0000
2012-03-01 15:14:48.125 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date: 20120831
2012-03-01 15:14:48.126 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date 2: 2012-01-31 00:00:00 +0000
2012-03-01 15:14:48.126 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date: 20120906
2012-03-01 15:14:48.127 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date 2: 2012-01-06 00:00:00 +0000
2012-03-01 15:14:48.127 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date: 20120907
2012-03-01 15:14:48.128 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date 2: 2012-01-07 00:00:00 +0000
2012-03-01 15:14:48.128 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date: 20120910
2012-03-01 15:14:48.128 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date 2: 2012-01-10 00:00:00 +0000
2012-03-01 15:14:48.129 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date: 20120913
2012-03-01 15:14:48.129 MyApp[21793:fb03] Adding date 2: 2012-01-13 00:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The day of month specifier is `dd`, not `DD`. Also, you might want to use the `yyyy` format for years, as `YYYY` means the ISO 'Week of Year', and may be different from the actual year. So your final format should look like:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
```

Comment: That fixed it! thanks. Odd that the `yyyy` and `dd` would have affected the month since that was the only characters that were right. LOL.